# Does the Vietnamese law prohibit non Vietnamese to work as lawyers in Vietnam?

Tags: employment, lawyer, vietnam

Does the Vietnamese law prohibit non Vietnamese to work as lawyers in Vietnam?

A "Vietnamese" for that matter is a citizen of the Socialist Republic of Vietnam.